# multiple date-picker dialog i want to use in one activity first time date is set but second time is not set proper

Tags: android

### here when i click the date picker dialog this is work properly first time.. than next time it will set the last datepicker dialog in android

##
     final int Date_Dialog_ID=0;
        final int Date_Dialog_ID1=1;
        final int Date_Dialog_ID2=2;
        private Calendar cal;
        private int day,month,year;
        int cur;

```
    //this is button click event
    trilcal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(Date_Dialog_ID);

            }
        });

        //this is button click event
        delcal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(Date_Dialog_ID1);

            }
        });

        //this is button click event
        bil_cal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(Date_Dialog_ID2);

            }
        });

     //this is dialog dynamically called 
      @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
          switch (id) {

            case Date_Dialog_ID:
                System.out.println("onCreateDialog  : " + id);
                cur = Date_Dialog_ID;
                // set date picker as current date
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                        day);
            case Date_Dialog_ID1:
                cur = Date_Dialog_ID1;
                System.out.println("onCreateDialog2  : " + id);
                // set date picker as current date
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                        day);

            case Date_Dialog_ID2:
                cur = Date_Dialog_ID2;
                System.out.println("onCreateDialog2  : " + id);
                // set date picker as current date
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                        day);

            }

            return null;

        }

    //this code through set the date is textview
      private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new           DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                    int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

                year = selectedYear;
                month = selectedMonth;
                day = selectedDay;

                if(cur == Date_Dialog_ID){

                    trildate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                            .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                            .append(" "));
                }

                if(cur == Date_Dialog_ID1){
                    deldate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                            .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                            .append(" "));
                }

                if(cur == Date_Dialog_ID2){
                    date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                            .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                            .append(" "));
                }        
            }
        }; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static final int Date_Dialog_ID=1;
static final int Date_Dialog_ID1=2;
static final int Date_Dialog_ID2=3;
private Calendar cal;
private int day,month,year;
int f_year, f_month, f_day,to_year, t_month, t_day; 
int cur=0;
```

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
  trilcal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(Date_Dialog_ID);

        }
    });

    delcal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(Date_Dialog_ID1);

        }
    });

    bil_cal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(Date_Dialog_ID2);

        }
    });
```

from_dateListener =new OnDateSetListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year1, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {

            year=year1;
            day=dayOfMonth;
            month=monthOfYear;
            trildate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));

        }
    };

      to_dateListener =new OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year1, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {

            year=year1;
            day=dayOfMonth;
            month=monthOfYear;
            deldate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));

        }
    };

    bil_dateListener =new OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year1, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {

            year=year1;
            day=dayOfMonth;
            month=monthOfYear;
            date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));

        }
    };
```

}

@Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
          switch (id) {

```
        case Date_Dialog_ID:
            System.out.println("onCreateDialog  : " + id);
            cur = Date_Dialog_ID;

            return new DatePickerDialog(this,f_day, f_dateListener, f_year,f_month,
                    f_day);

        case Date_Dialog_ID1:
            cur = Date_Dialog_ID1;
            System.out.println("onCreateDialog2  : " + id);

            return new DatePickerDialog(this,t_dateListener, t_year, t_month,
                    t_day);

        case Date_Dialog_ID2:
            cur = Date_Dialog_ID2;
            System.out.println("onCreateDialog2  : " + id);

            return new DatePickerDialog(this, b_dateListener, b_year, b_month,
                    b_day);

        }

        return null;

    }
```